# Combinatorics: How many 6 digit numbers have AT LEAST one '9' among them?

Tags: combinatorics

The Question is pretty simple and straight forward when we try to find the count of numbers without 9 and Subtracting that with Total arrangement of numbers
[9*10^5] - [8*9^5].

But how do you calculate without using a method like above?

This is what I thought, which is terribly awful.

(Sum of {Number of 6 digit nums with one '9' with 9 at each of the digits}) 
+ 
(Sum of {Number of 6 digit nums with two '9' with 2 '9's at different positions} ) 
+
so on...

Comment: Your suggested approach is good. More work, but not terribly awful. First count the numbers whose first digit is $9$. Easy. Then we want the number of numbers with something other than $9$ in first position. There are $8$ choices for first digit. For each choice, count the number of $5$-digit strings with at least one $9$. Exactly $5$ $9$'s, easy. Exactly $4$, $\binom{5}{4}9^4$. And so on.  By the way, your simple *expression* is right, but I think $472,392$ is not.

Comment: There are two kinds of people in the world: (a) those who include leading zeros when counting digits in a number, and (b) those who do not. To which category does @Abinesh belong?

Comment: @AndréNicolas  "For each choice, count the number of 5-digit strings with at least one 9. Exactly 5 9's, easy. Exactly 4, (54)94" What does that mean?
I think Exactly 5 9s means I can place the 5 9s in 5 Position... true.
Then the remaining 4 positions can be filled with 0 to 9, Am i right?
Wouldn't that mean (5*10^4)?

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi   Abinesh is the (a) guy

Comment: Exactly $5$ nines means we fill the places with nines, only one way to do it. Exactly $4$ means we choose the places where nines will go, $\binom{5}{4}=5$ ways to do it, then put anything other than nine in the remaining spot, total $(5)(9)$. Exactly $3$ nines means we choose $3$ places, $\binom{5}{3}=10$ ways, fill the remaining two spots with non nines, total $(10)(p^2)$. And so on.

Answer (score 3):

I like to suggest to see the problem as an extension of a simpler problem.

How many two-digit numbers do not have a $9$ in them? Fill in any number from $1$ to $8$ in the **tens** place, followed by any number from $0$ to $8$ in the **ones** place. How many possible numbers are there?

How many three-digit numbers do not have a $9$ in them? Fill in any number from $1$ to $8$ in the **hundreds** place, followed by any number from $0$ to $8$ in the **tens** place, and **ones** place. How many possible numbers are there?

How many four-digit numbers do not have a $9$ in them? Fill in any number from $1$ to $8$ in the **thousands** place, followed by any number from $0$ to $8$ in the **hundreds** place, the **tens** place, and **ones** place. How many possible numbers are there?

Get the drill? Extend this to six digit numbers.

Answer (score 2):

For two digits numbers the answer would be
$$
 \binom{2}{1}*10^1 - \binom{2}{1}*10^0 = 20 - 1 = 19
$$
For three digits numbers the answer would be
$$
 \binom{3}{1}*10^2 - \binom{3}{2}*10^1 + \binom{3}{3}*10^0 = 300 - 30 +1 = 271
$$
...

For six digits numbers the answer would be
$$
\eqalign{
 \binom{6}{1}*10^5 - \binom{6}{2}*10^4 + \binom{6}{3}*10^3  -\binom{6}{4}*10^2 + \binom{6}{5}*10^1 + \binom{6}{6}*10^0 &= \cr
600000-150000+20000-1500+60-1 &= 468559 \cr
}
$$